# How do I add a Listview Of BaseAdapter in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I want to add a `ListView` in a `Fragment` that uses a custom adapter extending `BaseAdapter`.
I don't want to try it through `ListFragment` because I've wriiten a lot of code in that fragment.
Can you help me to add a `ListView` in a `Fragment`.

```
adapter = new MyTableAdapter(getActivity(), list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and Adapter Class

```
public class MyTableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Root.StandingBean> list;
    Activity context;

    public MyTableAdapter(Activity context, List<Root.StandingBean> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_adapter, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView pos = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pos);
        TextView points = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.points);
        name.setText(list.get(position).getTeamName());
        pos.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        points.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getPoints()));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Also why are you passing `list` to the `MyTableAdapter` which I am assuming is the `ListView` since you are later calling `list.setAdapter(adapter)` on it?

Comment: @George actually ive just changed for sake of convenience but its actually a List<Root.Standing> list; 
favorite
Want to add a listview in Fragment having a customAdapter extends BaseAdapter , Dont want to try it through listFragment because ive wriiten a lot of code in that fragment help me to add a listView in a fragment .
List<Root.Standings> lr;
adapter = new MyTableAdapter(getActivity(), lr);

Comment: As long as the argument matches what the adapter requires you will be fine. What is the problem you are facing? What is not working in the posted code?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Actually its not showing the list of my data in listview not giving an error simply not showing it, i think its some issue with Constructor and its parameters ,Thanks for reply BTW.

Comment: In `MyTableAdapter` try also overriding the method `getCount()` and return `list.size()` in it. Also the method `getItem(...)`. Actually since your source is a list you would be better off extending from `ArrayAdapter<Root.StandingBean>`.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Thank you so much , It works , You Saved My Night Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.